# Adding a logo to my Navigation Pane using CSS (Squarespace site)

Tags: css, image, navigation, graphical-logo, squarespace

I'm trying to add in a sponsor logo into the top right corner of the Navigation Pane of my website using CSS.

Here is my website link: www.headlightshortfilm.com.au

Does anyone know how to do this using CSS? Squarespace can't help me so I was about to pay a Squarespace specialist to do it but I feel it must be pretty simple. I thought i'd try here first :)

Comment: [tag:logo] is a programming language.  Please don't use its tag for questions about graphical logos.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Div after your `<div id="topNav" style="padding-right: 0px;"></div>`

```
<div class="sponsored-logo">
    <img src="imageURL">
</div>
```

Add this class on your stylesheet

```
.sponsored-logo {
    float: right;
}
```

Add `float: left;` to your `#logo` and `#topNav`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!!! This may sound quite dumb, but I don't think I have div..? Here is what i've put in so far, no luck. Any thoughts?

Comment: Thank you so much for responding!!! This may sound quite dumb, but I don't think I have div..? Here is what i've put in so far, no luck. Any thoughts? FYI I've taken a screenshot but can't upload it here.
#topNav {
  url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54964a70e4b02f36a3b31eb8/t/54c4b339e4b0e75db38bdcc2/1422177081809/MetroScreen_logo_black_web.png)
}
#topNav {float: right;}

Comment: #topNav {
  url(http://static1.squarespace.com/static/54964a70e4b02f36a3b31eb8/t/54c4b339e4b0e75db38bdcc2/1422177081809/MetroScreen_logo_black_web.png)
}
#topNav {float: right;}